# SQL aggregate similar records

Tags: sql, metabase

I have a dataset that I need to query from and aggregate the selected records based on a string similarity.
For example a simple `SELECT, COUNT` query can return a set of records like:

| NAME | COUNT |
| --- | --- |
| CAR | 6 |
| CAR 1 | 12 |
| CAR 22 | 2 |
| CAR 45 | 9 |
| Van 2 | 4 |
| Van 22 | 5 |
| Van 12 | 16 |
| UNKNOWN | 6 |

I want the result to be aggregate by a substring as:

| NAME | COUNT |
| --- | --- |
| CAR | 29 |
| VAN | 25 |
| UNKOWN | 6 |

A sample of the current query I have is:

```
SELECT "vehicle_name" AS "NAME", count(*) AS "Count"
FROM "vehicles"
WHERE ("registered" = 'true'GROUP BY "public"."players"."device_name" 
ORDER BY "vehicle_name" ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the metabase [`regexextract`](https://www.metabase.com/docs/latest/users-guide/expressions-list.html#regexextract) function to solve your problem, matching the first word by exploiting the start of string symbol.

```
SELECT REGEXEXTRACT([NAME], "^[A-Za-z]+") AS "NAME", 
       SUM([COUNT])                       AS "COUNT"
FROM vehicles
GROUP BY REGEXEXTRACT([NAME], "^[A-Za-z]+")
```

Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks, I was able to achieve what I'm looking for based on your recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this

```
SELECT 
SUM(COUNT),
SUBSTRING(vehicle_name,1,ISNULL(NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[^A-Za-z.''0-9]%',LTRIM(RTRIM(vehicle_name))),0)-1,LEN(vehicle_name))) AS Value
FROM
vehicles
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(vehicle_name,1,ISNULL(NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[^A-Za-z.''0-9]%',LTRIM(RTRIM(vehicle_name))),0)-1,LEN(vehicle_name)))
```

Comment: Check for the OP's DBMS (metabase). This solution *may* work in SQL Server.